# Get complete graph from set of vertices?

Tags: function-construction, graphs-and-networks

There is a function in Mathematica called `CompleteGraph` which takes a number and makes a complete graph with that number of vertices:

```
CompleteGraph[5]
```

> [image]

However, in the above the vertices become labelled `{1,2,3,4,5}`. In contrast, given a set of vertices like e.g.,

```
vertices={1,3,5,6,8};
```

I would like to get a complete graph in which the vertices are labelled by the above labels. Is it possible to do that quickly (computationally efficiently) in Mathematica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RelationGraph[UnsameQ, vertices, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use any of the following to get the same result:

```
Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ Subsets[vertices, {2}], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
AdjacencyGraph[vertices, ConstantArray[1, {5,5}]-IdentityMatrix[5], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
SetProperty[VertexReplace[#, Thread[VertexList@# -> vertices]] &@ CompleteGraph[5],
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

To change just the labels you can use:

```
CompleteGraph[5, VertexLabels -> {k_ :> vertices[[k]]}]
```

> same picture

Comment: The first `CompleteGraph` approach seems to only change the labels but not the vertex names. The other two versions work great, thank you! (True, I guess my question was asking about labels, sorry for the confusion.)

Comment: @Kagaratsch, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

Using AdjacencyGraph:

```
AdjacencyGraph[vertices, 
 AdjacencyMatrix[CompleteGraph[Length[vertices]]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is with [`AdjacencyGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyGraph.html).

```
SimpleGraph[
 AdjacencyGraph[vertices, ConstantArray[1, Length[vertices] {1, 1}]],
 VertexLabels -> Automatic
]
```

[image]

With IGraph/M, you can zero out the matrix diagonal directly:

```
AdjacencyGraph[vertices, 
 IGZeroDiagonal@ConstantArray[1, Length[vertices] {1, 1}], 
 VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems the most direct method is to use `VertexReplace`, and it doesn't seem any slower than the other methods.

```
completeGraph[vertexList_List,opts___] := With[
    {g = CompleteGraph[ Length @ vertexList, opts]},
    VertexReplace[g, Thread[VertexList[g] -> vertexList]]
]
```

So you can do

```
completeGraph[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]